# Unable to create directory under NSHomeDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have code which creates a folder under the NSHomeDirectory but it always fails and I cannot see why. It should work but it keeps saying the operation is not permitted. Any ideas?

```
NSURL *homeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
NSURL *previewsURL = [homeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Previews"];

DebugLog(@"homeURL: %@", homeURL);
DebugLog(@"previewsURL: %@", previewsURL);

BOOL isDirectory = TRUE;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:previewsURL.path isDirectory:&isDirectory]) {
    DebugLog(@"isDirectory: %@", isDirectory ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSAssert(isDirectory, @"Must be a directory");

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:previewsURL.path withIntermediateDirectories:TRUE attributes:nil error:&error]) {
        DebugLog(@"Error: %@", error); // WHY?!
    }
    else {
        BOOL isDirectory = TRUE;
        BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:previewsURL.path isDirectory:&isDirectory];
        NSAssert(exists, @"Directory must exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating your directory inside e.g. ~/Documents instead? You may not be allowed to write to the home folder directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no permission to access NSHomeDirectory(),

Instead, create them in the documents directory

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *homeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectory isDirectory:YES];
NSURL *previewsURL = [homeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Previews"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it was not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as pointed out by other answers, you have no permissions to access home directory.

Then, I see you want to save some kind of previews: are they user-generated images, that **needs** to be saved, or are they just some kind of cached data that is written just to speed-up some kind of process (downloaded images, cached previews of larger versions of images..)?

If this is the case, you shouldn't use the document dir, as it should be used to save user-generated content only, content that your app **cannot** recreate by itself. The right directory for this kind of purposes is the cache one. If you don't follow this agreement, your App could be rejected by AppStore reviewal process.

```
NSString *cacheDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *cacheURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cacheDirectory isDirectory:YES];
NSURL *previewsURL = [cacheURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Previews"];
```

Comment: Yes, I am considering using the Caches folder. This is for an iCloud app and so far the examples do not use the Caches folder which I think is odd for preview files.

Comment: Can previews files be recreated on demand from other versions of the files? If the answer is yes, they should go to the Cache dir, while original versions should go on document dir, in order to sync them on iCloud. Previews should then be recreated by your code if they are not already stored inside the cache dir.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: because you can't/aren't permitted to write to that directory (because it's outside the app sandbox).