# What is NSHomeDirectory? When it is used?

Tags: ios

I want to understand the two commonly used, `NSDocumentDirectory` which I have used in `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`. The other one is `NSHomeDirectory`. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Minor point to your question: I'm curious you think it's common to use `NSHomeDirectory()` on iOS. It really isn't – you should request the path to the subfolder you want, e.g. documents or caches. [See this answer for some interesting commentary.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325065/unable-to-create-directory-under-nshomedirectory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSHomeDirectory()` returns the root directory for your sandboxed app on iOS, but it's not recommended to use this.

If you want to read and write files, the most common places to use are the documents directory and the caches directory. Use the former for things you want to save for a long period of time, and the latter for things you want to save only temporarily. Apple provides specific ways to find these two directories rather than trying to access them through the home directory, so you should use it: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()`.

[Lots](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2sj6AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA457&lpg=PA457&dq=ios+nshomedirectory+documents&source=bl&ots=Qq6MT_Mf8g&sig=r2wc3jLB5ZzEpH1YnXwPk6B4uso&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH8uylqOvJAhVEbRQKHas1Bko4ChDoAQgwMAM#v=onepage&q=ios%20nshomedirectory%20documents&f=false) [of](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/where-to-store-files) [tutorials](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/iphone-file-system-creating-renaming-and-deleting-files.html) [use](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TbNtvo8rXM0C&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=nshomedirectory+ios+documents&source=bl&ots=6ZPsuXlqu5&sig=ESMSZSMd-tssguTmUZtaoToQ454&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip27ehquvJAhUHtxoKHRXSBFc4FBDoAQg7MAU#v=onepage&q=nshomedirectory%20ios%20documents&f=false) [NSHomeDirectory](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90773/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-2), and it wouldn't exactly be hard for Apple to remove the function from iOS if they really wanted it dead. However, in practice you should use the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` function to locate standard directories like Documents and Library/Caches – they could be moved anywhere at any time in the future, so it's sensible to ask iOS where they are rather than try to hard-code paths.

In summary, here's a comment I posted to the original question: "I'm curious you think it's common to use NSHomeDirectory() on iOS. It really isn't – you should request the path to the subfolder you want, e.g. documents or caches." The function exists, and many people use it, but I would strongly suggest you do not.

Comment: You should never use `NSHomeDirectory` in iOS. Do not assume that the Documents folder or the Caches folder is inside `NSHomeDirectory`. There are proper ways to access specific folders.

Comment: @rmaddy: See my comment to his question – "you should request the path to the subfolder you want". I wonder if I should append that comment to my answer to be absolutely clear.

Comment: Your comment is one thing, this answer is another. As written, this answer has some incorrect and misleading information.

Comment: I have attempted to clarify.

Comment: I am curious: which part of the first paragraph is wrong?

Comment: The assumption that the Documents and Caches folder are in the home folder.

Comment: Thank you; I have restructured my answer to strongly re-enforce that `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` is the only viable solution.